# Samsung SCX-3200 how to check what error?

Tags: printer

Samsung SCX-3200 has red light on, how to get the information about the error?

Comment: Have you checked the manual? Does the LCD display any error code?

Comment: No it does not, manual says that it may mean low toner, but hot to check it?

Comment: You can try taking out the toner cartridge and rolling it around gently in order to redistribute any leftover toner evenly, but besides that I don't know how to check whether there really is any toner left or not.